# Can't save a numpy 2-d array into a file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have the following 2-d numpy matrix, which was a concatenation of two matrices:

```
     >>> mnist1_train_final_data=np.hstack((y_train_mnist_ni,features_train_mnist1))
     >>> type(mnist1_train_final_data)
     <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
     >>> mnist1_train_final_data.dtype
     dtype('S32')
     >>> mnist1_train_final_data.shape
      (1149, 129)
```

As you can see, it is a 2-d numpy array. However, when I try to save it using the following command:

```
>>> np.savetxt('test.txt', mnist1_train_final_data, delimiter=',', fmt='%5.2f')
```

It shows me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
<module>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py",
line 1162, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format)) TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S32') and format specifier
('%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f')
```

How can I save a 2-d numpy matrix in my case?

Comment: Are you expecting the array to contain strings?  `savetxt` iterates on the rows, and for each row does `fmt%tuple(row)`, where `fmt` is that string in the 'mismatch'.  There's one `%f5.2` for each of the 129 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S32` is a string type.  The format you're specifying is for float types.  To save a string type, with `savetxt` you need to pass the `"%s"` formatter.  Note that the default format is not valid for string types so you *must* pass a valid string formatter such as `"%s"`

`np.savetxt('test.txt', mnist1_train_final_data, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')`