# Write chararray to file in Numpy, Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a chararray to file using:

```
np.savetxt("output.csv", output_matrix, delimiter=",")
```

however doing so gives me the following error:

```
Mismatch between array dtype ('<U10000') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')
```

I am a little bit confused how do I change the dtype of the savetext method?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.tofile.html

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: descriptor 'tofile' requires a 'numpy.ndarray' object but received a 'str'

However the type of my output_matrix is numpy.core.defchararray.chararray so I am unsure why it consider it a str

Comment: You have to call it like this: `output_matrix.tofile('output.csv')`

Comment: Got it, thanks! However the output is rather odd, I scraped a website for data with 4 columns, title, body, author, origin. In my chararray every element is in a specific column, however in the output everything gets completely jumbled around. Do you know why? Sorry for the semi terrible explanation

Comment: Sorry, I've no experience working with chararrays. Maybe use pandas instead of you're storing a large amount of tabular data?

Comment: Yeah good point I will do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't save a numpy 2-d array into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910803/cant-save-a-numpy-2-d-array-into-a-file)

Comment: `fmt='%s'` in `savetxt` can save string elements.  But '<U10000` suggests you array contains one big string, not may small ones.  Is `output matrix` really an array, and if so what's its shape?

Comment: I ended up converting it to a panda dataframe, however its shape is (800,14), but reach cell has a long string in it. I converted it through: output_df=pd.DataFrame(data=output_matrix,
                          columns=col_names)